# ElasticSearch Node Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch cluster dropped from 2B documents to 900M Records, on AWS it shows

> Relocating shards: 4

Whilst Showing

> Active Shards: 35

and

> Active primary shards: 34

(Might not be relevant but here's rest of stats):

> Number of nodes: 9
>
> Number of data nodes: 6
>
> Unassigned shards: 17

When running

```
GET /_cluster/allocation/explain
```

it returns:

```
{
  "index": "datauwu",
  "shard": 6,
  "primary": true,
  "current_state": "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info": {
    "reason": "NODE_LEFT",
    "at": "2019-10-31T17:02:11.258Z",
    "details": "node_left[removedforsecuritybecimparanoid1]",
    "last_allocation_status": "no_valid_shard_copy"
  },
  "can_allocate": "no_valid_shard_copy",
  "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because a previous copy of the primary shard existed but can no longer be found on the nodes in the cluster",
  "node_allocation_decisions": [
    {
      "node_id": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid2",
      "node_name": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid2",
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "found": false
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid3",
      "node_name": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid3",
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "found": false
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid4",
      "node_name": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid4",
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "found": false
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid5",
      "node_name": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid5",
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "found": false
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid6",
      "node_name": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid6",
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "found": false
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid7",
      "node_name": "removedforsecuritybecimparanoid7",
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "found": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

im a bit confused to what this exactly means, does this mean my elasticsearch cluster did not lose data, but is instead relocating it into different shards, or cannot it not find the shards?

If it cannot find shards, does this mean my data was lost? if so, what could be the reason, how can i prevent this from happening in the future?

I haven't setup replicas as i was indexing data, and replicas slow it down whilst indexing.

also side not, my record count dropped down to 400m at one point but then rose back up to 900m randomly. i don't know what this means and any insight would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to recover an unallocated shard with a missing primary using `allocate_stale_primary` [as described by Chris Heald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58758132/4288232) you might get:

```
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "No data for shard [0] of index [xyz] found on any node"
      }
```

This mean the data is gone unless the missing node rejoins the cluster. Alternatively, you can [empty the shard](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/elasticsearch-unassigned-shards/#reason-4-shard-data-no-longer-exists-in-the-cluster) using an `allocate_empty_primary` command.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -XPOST '127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty' -d '{
    "commands" : [ {
        "allocate_empty_primary" :
            {
              "index" : "datauwu", "shard" : 6,
              "node" : "target-data-node-id",
              "accept_data_loss" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

This wipe the data and will overwrite the shard if the missing node rejoins.

Answer (score 5):

> "reason": "NODE_LEFT"

And:

> I haven't setup replicas as i was indexing data, and replicas slow it down whilst indexing.

If the node holding the primary shards has gone away, then yes, your data is gone. After all, if there are no replicas, then where would the cluster retrieve the data from, if the primary (and only) shards are no longer part of the cluster? You will either need to bring the node holding those shards back up and add it into the cluster, or the data is gone.

The error message is saying "You want me to allocate a primary shard for this index that I know exists, but there used to be another version of that primary shard that can't be found anymore, I won't allocate it again in case the previous primary comes back."

You can force Elasticsearch to reallocate the primary shard (and explicitly accept that the data in the previous primary shard is gone) by performing a reroute with `allocate_stale_primary` ([doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html)):

```sh
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -XPOST '127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty' -d '{
    "commands" : [ {
        "allocate_stale_primary" :
            {
              "index" : "datauwu", "shard" : 6,
              "node" : "target-data-node-id",
              "accept_data_loss" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Turning off replicas for anything but development with disposable data is usually a bad idea.

> also side not, my record count dropped down to 400m at one point but then rose back up to 900m randomly. i don't know what this means and any insight would greatly be appreciated.

This happens because shards aren't visible in the cluster. This can happen if all copies of a shard are being allocated, relocated, or recovered. This corresponds with a RED cluster state. You can mitigate it by ensuring that you have at least 1 replica (though ideally you have a sufficient number of replicas set up to survive the loss of N data nodes in the cluster). This lets Elasticsearch keep one shard as the primary while it moves others around.

If you only have the primary and no replicas, then if a primary is being recovered or relocated, the data in that shard will not be visible in the cluster. Once the shard is active again, the documents in it become visible.

Comment: thanks chris, how would i go about bringing back the node? any docs i can read or follow?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics of AWS' ES offerings, but you would generally just need to bring the machine holding the data back online, then start the ES daemon and wait for it to rejoin the cluster and recover any shards it holds. NODE_LEFT indicates that either the ES service got stopped on a machine, or the machine itself was stopped (or a network partition developed between that node and the rest of the cluster).

Comment: thanks chris, it seems to be a bug or something with AWS, could it simply be relocating data instead? or is it down for a fact?

Comment: NODE_LEFT indicates that the node left the cluster - it's either offline, or the network is partitioned. It's not relocating. I'm not sure what guarantees AWS makes as to node durability, though a quick review of their pricing page seems to indicate they only offer ondemand or RIs, no spots, which should usually stick around. Are you using AWS' Elasticsearch service, or just running ES on EC2 machines? Do you have any instances with the ES daemon stopped?

Comment: Thanks again chris, im using an RI ElasticSearch Service. I'll contact them and see what's going on.

Comment: yeah this is really odd, for some reason AWS added 3 more data instances, which are not on my RI and they're currently transferring data to them from what i can see, it seems like their was a failure on their part. The sad thing is, this all costs me bandwith to reindex. I'm going to contact them regarding this now.

Comment: Good luck with it! Turn those replicas up! :)